# What do the sea serpents represent?

Tags: analysis, 300-rise-of-an-empire

In [300 Rise of an Empire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1253863/), what do the sea serpents represent? Are they meant to symbolize something or is it a random piece from mythology? If they are meant to be from greek mythology, what are these particular sea serpents called?

Comment: Firstly I dont think anything from either of the 300 movies are too in depth about anything. Don't get me wrong there good movies, they just don't make that much sense. An there's no secondly so I Donno why I said firstly

Comment: can you provide more detail about which scene or scenario is the sea serpent mentioned

Comment: The Art of 300: Rise of an Empire refers to them as "Sea Monsters". No explanation is given for their presence.

Answer (score 3):

The movie "300 Rise of an Empire" isn't about accuracy but about action. It is inspired by greek history but it is not a historic movie.

Even from the prequel the movie "300" Zack Snyder tried to create a movie that doesn't obey any law, physical, logical or historical. I personally like the movie but we must not try to explain it logically and in depth because it is based upon a comic.

So to answer your question the purpose of the sea serpent it to create a more "powerful" scene and to make the movie move intense. There are fights and naval battles and it adds to the action the emergence of a sea monster (while totally useless in my opinion). There was no reason for that serpent to be there and I personally think that he tried to exploit visual effects even more than in the prequel. While in the prequel you could think that we are still in a real world in this movie there are a lot of elements that just don't belong there!

The "300" was an excellent action movie and without these extreme and useless monster scenes that exist in the sequel. So he saw that it was a hit and tried to add even more fantasy things into it. That is a reason that this movie wasn't such a success as its prequel.

Comment: Actually, the physical and factual inaccuracies in the original *300* can be explained by the fact that it's an in-universe propaganda piece, being recited by one of the Spartans at the end of the film to motivate his colleagues ahead of a major battle. I haven't seen *Rise of an Empire* so I can't say if the same holds true for that particular film.

Answer (score 2):

I just finished Dan Carlin’s Hardcore History podcast trilogy “King of Kings” he published in the mid-2010’s and the sea serpent scene is actually an allusion to a passage from Herodotus’ ancient account of the Greco-Persian wars from his “Histories”!
“Twenty-thousand men devoured by sea monsters..”

I think that was really just a fun nod to obviously the source material it was based off. Apparently Herodotus’ “Histories” may have very well been written as something akin to a modern screenplay to be acted out on a Greek stage so many elements of his historical accounts tend to deviate in wildly ways not unlike Zach Snyder‘s film or Frank Miller’s graphic novel